# IIS Session Sharing between Two IIS Instances

Tags: sql-server, iis, load-balancing, session

For testing purposes, I have 2 sites on the same IIS server that I want the session state to be shared between. The sites are identical (they point to the same folder) and originally they used the default application pool (which I have switched to the classic .NET app pool).

I changed the session state globally in IIS to use SQL server and both sites have an identical connection string.

When I hop from one site (alpha) to the other (bravo), the state is not shared and I am forced to start over.

Can anyone offer some suggestions regarding what I should try next to get this working? Any help is appreciated. Thanks,

mj

Answer (score 1):

Do the servers have different hostnames for your testing?

Check what the domain is on the session cookie that you get - you may not be sending the cookie to the second server that you got from the first server.

If that is the issue, then probably the easiest way to properly test would be in the hosts file (`c:\windows\system32\drivers\etc\hosts`) - set `application.domain.com` to be the first server's address, connect and start a session, then change the address in the hosts file to the second server and see if the session stuck.

Comment: My testing websites have two different domains - alpha and bravo. Since they're on the same machine, they have a common hostname.  

I think you're right about the cookie. I just checked in Firefox and the ASPSESSIONIDAAATDQSS cookie values are different between the two sites. So I just need to send that value from A to B? I'll give that a shot.